# How to recover boot menu if I lost my password during the installation

Tags: boot, password-recovery

I got a new laptop with ubuntu ready to be installed from the factory. I installed to near the end that it's ask me to key-in login, password, retyped password and computer name. Then, I came to my old laptop to do something else. When I went back, it showed me the normal login page.

But I try to login but it's falied. I know exactly what my password is but the problem is it may be too long and it may be accidentally the same with the retyped.

I thought that it's now a problem since I just re-install it from the boot menu using one from factory.

But the problem is that there is no more boot menu. So how can I bring back the boot menu?

I have tried everything in this question:

- [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)

Either left shift, right shift or both didn't help. That's why my question is 'bring back' rather than 'display'.

Comment: Hello Jessada, please have a look at this question [How do I reset a lost Administrative(root) password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password) and let us know if it solves the issue you are having.

Comment: I saw that before asked this question. I tried it several time. Either left shift, right shift or both didn't help. That's why my question is 'bring back' rather than 'display'.

Comment: Perhaps it is not a password problem. go to a console (ctrl-alt-F2) and try to log in. Check your logs for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is really "how do I display the boot menu?". You do that by holding down the shift key when you boot.